# How can i Apply a OnClickListener to a LinearLayouts Child?

Tags: java, android

This is my code, trying to pass a listener to each child. Each child is a picture that i need to know which one is clicked so i can start the imagePager from that picture.
But with this code the Childs do not get clicked. Help Please.

```
    thumbs_layout.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImagePager.class);
                intent.putExtra("CHILD_INDEX", view.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use View v = thumbs_layout.getChildAt(i); 
v.setTag(xxxx);
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImagePager.class);
                intent.putExtra("CHILD_INDEX", v.getTag);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your click listener to all the childs within your Layout like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < layoutParent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View view = layoutParent.getChildAt(i);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImagePager.class);
            intent.putExtra("CHILD_INDEX", view.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: im sorry i do have the loop, but mistakenly didnt show it here, thats why i have "getChildAt(i)". its just that the listener doesnt get triggered when i touch the picture